# python osmnx - extract all network from Portugal

Tags: python-3.x, osmnx

I'm trying to extract all network from Portugal but without success. I did not have any result. Could be possible to check if my code is correct? Something is wrong. I'm using Jupyter notebook.

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import requests
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
ox.__version__

region = {'country':'Portugal'}
G = ox.graph_from_place(region, network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

Comment: You said "without success" but please edit your question to provide complete details about what exactly *is* happening. I see you configured logging on, so please also provide the complete log output.

Comment: I test again using cmd.exe python provided by anaconda environments and I did it. I think that the problem was used the Jupiter notebook. Thank you for your preoccupation.

Comment: Now works for me. I'm sorry by my poor explanation. I appreciate your python package.

Comment: No worries. Glad to hear it's working.