# osmnx - how would do I do extract the road network of a whole country?

Tags: osmnx

I know Europe's road network is about 18M nodes, which is not that big.
I wonder if someone know how to extract the road network of a whole country.
Via `OSMNx` or something else, it seems that it is impossible. `Pyrosm` can do it for very small country. I do not understand why it is so difficult since the number of nodes should not be too big.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python osmnx - extract only big freeways of a country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231122/python-osmnx-extract-only-big-freeways-of-a-country)

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66079561/7321942 https://stackoverflow.com/q/72213098/7321942 https://stackoverflow.com/q/63194193/7321942 https://stackoverflow.com/q/52231122/7321942

Comment: The problem is that it fullfill the RAM very quickly then the kernel crash. It is really frustrating because I'm pretty sure 2 millions nodes graph should not take a lot of disk space. I think OSMNx need to compute a lot of temporary things to build the graph, that is maybe the reason why?